# How to declare dynamic PHP class with {'property-names-like-this'}

Tags: php, class, dynamic

Im rewriting application from .NET to PHP.
I need to create class like this:

```
class myClass
{
    public ${'property-name-with-minus-signs'} = 5;
    public {'i-have-a-lot-of-this'} = 5; //tried with "$" and without
}
```

But it doesnt work.
I dont want to use something like this:

```
$myClass = new stdClass();
$myClass->{'blah-blah'};
```

Because i have a lot of this in code.

Edit few days later: i was writing application that uses SOAP. These fancy names are used in API which i had to communicate with.

Comment: Why do you need the curly braces? What's wrong with just doing `public $property-name-with-minus-signs = 5`?

Comment: @Jam Uhm... it doesn't work? :)

Comment: @JamWaffles: Maybe... the syntax error? :)

Comment: @deceze I will leave my comment up as a self-shaming. I know you can use underscores but it never occurred to me that a dash might be a minus sign! It's 3:10am. I should go to bed.

Comment: @Kamil Why do you *need* properties with dashes in the first place? PHP isn't .NET, and dashes in variable or property names are uncommon in the PHP world (guess why; because they don't work). CamelCasing is the usual way to write those.

Comment: @deceze: I don't think you can use dashes in identifiers in *any* .NET language, either.

Comment: @Kamil be sure to select the answer that solved your question.

Comment: @JamWaffles minus sign is interpreted as substract operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used code like this:

```
class myClass
{

    function __construct() {

        // i had to initialize class with some default values
        $this->{'fvalue-string'} = '';
        $this->{'fvalue-int'} = 0;
        $this->{'fvalue-float'} = 0;
        $this->{'fvalue-image'} = 0;
        $this->{'fvalue-datetime'} = 0;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You cannot use hyphens (dashes) in PHP class properties.
PHP variable names, class properties, function names and method names must begin with a letter or underscore `([A-Za-z_])` and may be followed by any number of digits `([0-9])`.

You can get around this limitation by using member overloading:

```php
class foo
{
    private $_data = array(
        'some-foo' => 4,
    );

    public function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->_data[$name])) {
            return $this->_data[$name];
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->_data[$name] = $value;
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
var_dump($foo->{'some-foo'});
$foo->{'another-var'} = 10;
var_dump($foo->{'another-var'});
```

However, I would heavily discourage this method as it is very intensive and just generally a bad way to program. Variables and members with dashes are not common in either PHP or .NET as has been pointed out.

Comment: As i wrote - they works (as dynamic properties, but i need to clone that class and i need default value in cloned class.

Comment: @Kamil Set default in the constructor. Or I have a good idea! Don't use identifiers that contain a hyphen! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`__get` magic method](http://php.net/__get) to achieve this, although it may become inconvenient, depending on the purpose:

```
class MyClass {
    private $properties = array(
        'property-name-with-minus-signs' => 5
    );

    public function __get($prop) {
        if(isset($this->properties[$prop])) {
            return $this->properties[$prop];
        }

        throw new Exception("Property $prop does not exist.");
    }
}
```

It should work well for your purposes, however, considering that `-`s aren't allowed in identifiers in most .NET languages anyway and you're probably using an indexer, which is analogous to `__get`.