# Codeigniter: Passing data from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

I want to pass `$data` from the controller named `poll`  to the `results_view` however I am getting an undefined variable error.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Poll extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->helper('form');
       }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('poll_view',$data);
    }

    public function vote()
    {
        echo "Voting Successfull";
        $this->db->insert('votes',$_POST);
    }

    public function results()
    {
        echo "These are the results";
        //$query = $this->db->get('votes');
        $data = "hello";
        $this->load->view('results_view', $data);

    }
}
```

Results_view.php

```
<html>
<?php echo $data; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: $data should be array not variable

Answer (score 51):

`$data` should be an array or an object: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

```
$data = array(
    'title' => 'My Title',
    'heading' => 'My Heading',
    'message' => 'My Message'
);

$this->load->view('results_view', $data);
```

**results_view.php**

```
<html>
<?php 
//Access them like so
echo $title.$heading.$message; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: i have read the article about how to pass data From Controller To View In CodeIgniter     http://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-pass-data-in-codeigniter/

Comment: @Lawrence I tried your code, which is working after clicked but before If I refreshed the view page then I am getting Undefined variable:  Any help?

Comment: @NarendraVerma you're probably using a $_GET param somewhere and not checking its set before using.

Answer (score 22):

In simple terms,

`$data['a']` in controller becomes `$a` in your view. (`$data` won't exist in your view, only the index will become available)

e.g.

```
Controller:    
$data['hello']='hellow world';

view:
echo $hello;
```

Comment: Yes, you right. $data doesn't exist on view directly. Best way to pass the value on view it's by $data['hello']

Answer (score 7):

You just need to create a array, you using codeigniter right?

Example on controller:

```
$data['hello'] = "Hello, world";
$this->load->view('results_view', $data);
```

In de page "results_view" you just have to:

```
<?php echo $hello;?>
```

Obs: You can create n datas, just pay attention in the name and make it a array.

Obs²: To use the data use the key of the array with a echo.

Comment: I tried your code, which is working after clicked but before If I refreshed the page I am getting Undefined variable: hello. Any help?

Answer (score 6):

The view wouldn't call the data 'data'

The controller would include an associative index (not sure if that's correct nomenclature) for data e.g 'stuff' looking thus `$data['stuff']`

You'd `echo` in the view so: `echo $stuff;` not `echo $data;`

I am a v lowly code fiddler but do really like CodeIgniter so excuse me if i've got this arse about tit.

One more thing - surely your constructor function is a bit of a waste. All that loading of libraries and helpers is done with the autoload file.

Answer (score 4):

You can create property `$data = []`; inside CI_Controller(path: system/core/Controller.php) and store all data to show in view. U can load common data like languages, menu, etc in CI_Controller. Also u can add special data for view in controller. (example: `$this->data['message'] = "Hello world";`)
Finally, u can pass `$this->data` to view when load view (example: `$this->load->view('view_name',$this->data);`)

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way

defined array in **controller**

```
$data['hello'] = "hello";
```

and pass variable to **view**

```
echo $hello;
```

Comment: This answer only adds redundant info to the page and can be safely removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass

```
$data = your code
$this->load->view('your-page', $data);
```

and get data on your view as

```
<?php echo $data;?>
```

It won't work because ci didn't understand this patern. If like to pass value form controller to view so you can try this -

controller -

```
$data['any-name'] = your values;
$this->load->view('your-page', $data);
```

then in your view you can get this data by -

```
<?php echo $any-name;?>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9322340/2943403 the parts of this answer that are correct are redundant.  This post can safely be removed.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can pass

```
$data['poll'] = "Your results";
```

In your view you can call

```
echo $poll;
```

Comment: This answer only adds redundant info to the page and can be safely removed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I finally solved it. You should really have a model (it helps a lot)

In your model do something like

**Model**

```
class poll_model extends CI_MODEL {

 function __construct() {
   $this-load->database(); 
 }

 function get_poll {
   $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
   $row = $query->row();

   $obj = array(
    'id' => $row->id
  );
   return $obj;
 }
}
```

Now if you have more than an id say name of poll # you can add in array. 
   Now in your **controller** do

```
class Poll extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model('poll_model');
   }

public function index()
{
    $data["a"] = $this->poll_model->get_poll();
    $this->load->view('poll_view',$data);
}
```

And finally in **VIEW** put

```
<? echo $a["id"]; ?>
```

This is a big help. I figured it out by testing and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In controller:

```
$data["result"] = $this->login_model->get_login(); // Get array value from DB..

$this->load->view('login-form',$data); // Pass the array to view
```

In view:

```
print_r($result);  // print the array in view file
```

Comment: This answer only adds redundant info to the page and can be safely removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen all above answer so here is what I do when I have to load the data from the controller to my view. 
To Pass the Data To the view from the controller:

```
public function your_controller(){

   // Your Necessary Code 
   // You have the $data, $data2, $data3 to post to the view.

   $this->load->view('your_view_directory or view_page',['data'=>$data, 'data2'=>$data2, 'data3'=>$data3... so on ]);

}
```

And At the View Side You can simply retrieve that data:
To Display You can simply use `echo`, `print`, `print_r`. And if you want to loop over it, you can do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

**In controller:**

public function product(){

```
$data = array("title" => "Books", "status"=>"Read","author":"arshad","company":"3esofttech",
```

"subject":"computer science");

***Data From Model to controller***

```
$this->load->model('bookModel');
$result = $this->bookModel->getMoreDetailsOfBook();

**Add *$result* from model to *$data* array**  
$data['tableRows'] = $result;
```

**$data from Controller to View**

```
$this->load->view('admin/head',$data);
```

**And to access in view file**
views/user.php

```
<?php  echo $data;
 foreach($tableRows as $row){ echo
 $row['startData']; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$data = "hello";
$this->load->view('results_view', $data);
```

Do

```
$data['hello'] = 'hello';
$this->load->view('results_view', $data);
```

In your controller file and controller will send **data** having **hello** as *string* to results_view and in your view file you can simply access by

```
echo $hello;
```

Comment: This answer only adds redundant info to the page and can be safely removed.