# Passing JSON from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, json, codeigniter

I made an API call and received the response in JSON format.

JSON:

```js
{
  "Specialities": [
    {
      "SpecialityID": 1,
      "SpecialityName": "Eye Doctor"
    },
    {
      "SpecialityID": 2,
      "SpecialityName": "Chiropractor"
    },
    {
      "SpecialityID": 3,
      "SpecialityName": "Primary Care Doctor"
    }
  ]
}
```

Controller File:

```html
public function index(){
      $data= json_decode(file_get_contents('some_url'));
      $this->load->view('my_view',$data);
}
```

Above code doesn't work because in view I can't access the nested object properties. However I am able to echo the JSON properties in controller file just like this:

Controller File:

```html
public function index(){

     $data=json_decode(file_get_contents('some_url'));
     foreach ($data as $key=>$prop_name){
        for($i=0;$i < count($prop_name);$i++){
          echo $prop_name[$i]->SpecialityID;
          echo $prop_name[$i]->SpecialityName;
        }
     }
}
```

My question is how do I pass this JSON to view and how can I access those properties in view file?

Comment: you need to pass data in array to `VIEW` like ===>  `$data['myJson'] = json_decode(file_get_contents('some_url'));
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);`

Comment: For better understanding you can see this link to read data in view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446700/codeigniter-passing-data-from-controller-to-view?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view)

> Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of **an array** or
> **an object** in the second parameter of the view loading method.
>
> **Here is an example using an array:**

So you need to change your code in controller

**Controller.php**

```
$data = array();
$data['myJson'] = json_decode(file_get_contents('some_url'));
$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
```

**my_view.php**

```
<html>
....
<?php 
//Access them like so
print_r($myJson);
// Rest of your code here to play with json 
?>
....
</html>
```

Comment: shukran :-) @Sidra

Answer (score 2):

In controller changes like

```
public function index(){
      $data['json_data']= json_decode(file_get_contents('some_url'));
      $this->load->view('my_view',$data);
}
```

and in the view

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($json_data);
```