# Fetch checkbox values from DB MySQL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Ok so I went through some of the questions similar to my question but i did not get what to do with mine.
I have a function in my model to get single restaurant from db, and i have a field that holds all the opening days of the particular restaurant as comma separated value, (1,2,3) 1 = Sunday 2 = Monday 3 = Tuesday and so on up to 7...

[DB Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiXmq.png)

and i want to check the checkbox when the restaurant has opening days like if restaurant one is having 1,2,3 it should check Sunday, Monday and Tuesday from front-end view..
Here is my model... Sorry for so long question... Pls help to how to do it...

```
function get_single_restaurant($id){
    $this->db->from('restaurants');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $output = '' ;
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i> View Restaurant</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="view_restaurant_name">Restaurant Name </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="view_restaurant_name" id="view_restaurant_name" value="'.$row->restaurant_name.'" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="view_max_pax">Maximun No. of Pax </label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="view_max_pax" id="view_max_pax" value="'.$row->max_pax.'" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name"><b>Opening Days </b></label>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_days" name="opening_days[]" id="view_sunday" value="1" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_sunday">'.$row->opening_days.'</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_days" name="opening_days[]" id="view_monday" value="2" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_monday">Monday</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_days" name="opening_days[]" id="view_tuesday" value="3" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_tuesday">Tuesday</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_days" name="opening_days[]" id="view_wednesday" value="4" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_wednesday">Wednesday</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_days" name="opening_days[]" id="view_thursday" value="5" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_thursday">Thursday</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_days" name="opening_days[]" id="view_friday" value="6" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_friday">Friday</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_days" name="opening_days[]" id="view_saturday" value="7" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_saturday">Saturday</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name"><b>Meal Times </b><span class="text-theme-color">*</span></label>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_meal_times" name="view_breakfast" id="view_breakfast" value="1" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_breakfast">Breakfast</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_meal_times" name="view_lunch" id="view_lunch" value="2" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_lunch">Lunch</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_meal_times" name="view_dinner" id="view_dinner" value="3" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_dinner">Dinner</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_meal_times" name="view_evening_class" id="view_evening_class" value="4" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_evening_class">Evening Class</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_meal_times" name="view_morning_class" id="view_morning_class" value="5" disabled>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="view_morning_class">Morning Class</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="description"><b>Description</b></label>
              <textarea name="view_restaurant_description" id="view_restaurant_description" class="form-control" disabled>'.$row->restaurant_description.'</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="view_restaurant_status"><b>Restaurant Status</b></label><br>
                      <h6>'.$row->restaurant_status.'</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>                        
                    ';
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Here Is my View in front-end

[Front-End View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrqc0.png)

And this is my Controller

```
function getRestaurant(){
    $id = $this->input->post('restaurant_id');
    $data = $this->sm->get_single_restaurant($id);
    if($this->sm->get_single_restaurant($id)){
        echo $data;
    }else{
        $data = array(
            'StatusCode' => '0',
            'message' => 'Invalid request'
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing CodeIgniter, it seems you need to map the values to a clear representation in your UI. But maybe you can try to be more clear in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to `javascript` rather than `php/codeigniter`.
Nevertheless, what you need is make a separate `checkbox` and give it a value of all the fields you want to be selected when `clicked`(like you're doing), give it some `id`, add an `event(change)`, then give `attribute` to all the `inputs` with their day number and select accordingly.
I've created a working snippet(without the `php` of course), comments are mentioned wherever necessary. See if it helps you.

```js
document.querySelector('#special').addEventListener('change', (event) => { // add event 'change' to id='special'
  let elements = event.target.value.split(','); // get the value and create an array by splitting it
 
  let checked = false; // default false
  if (event.target.checked) { // check if the checkbox is checked or unchecked
    checked = true; // change if checked
  }
  
  elements.forEach((item) => { // change the property of all the checkboxes where data-day = item
    document.querySelector('[data-day="'+item+'"]').checked = checked;
  });
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1,2,3" id="special">1,2,3&nbsp; 
<!-- 
Give an id='special'  and value='1,2,3' for Sunday, Monday, Tuesday 
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add_days" id='special' name="opening_days[]" id="view_sunday" value="'.$row->opening_days.'">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="view_sunday">'.$row->opening_days.'</label>
-->
<input type="checkbox" value="1" data-day="1" name="opening_days[]" id="view_monday">Sunday&nbsp; <!-- add attribut data-day with its value = day number -->
<input type="checkbox" value="2" data-day="2" name="opening_days[]" id="view_monday">Monday&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" value="3" data-day="3" name="opening_days[]" id="view_tuesday">Tuesday&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" value="4" data-day="4" name="opening_days[]" id="view_wednesday">Wednesday&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" value="5" data-day="5" name="opening_days[]" id="view_thursday">Thursday&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" value="6" data-day="6" name="opening_days[]" id="view_friday">Friday&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" value="7" data-day="7" name="opening_days[]" id="view_saturday">Saturday&nbsp;
```

### Edit 1

Ok, so I guess, I misunderstood your question, what you want is to check the `checkboxes` with the values already stored in the `database`.
You can do this like so -

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row->opening_days; ?>" id="special"><?php echo $row->opening_days; ?>

<?php 
    // make an array of the values - 
    $element = explode(",", $row->opening_days));
?>

<input type="checkbox" value="1" data-day="1" name="opening_days[]" id="view_sunday" <?php echo in_array("1", $element) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>Sunday 
<!-- if 1(day number) is present in array element then check else unchecked -->
<input type="checkbox" value="2" data-day="2" name="opening_days[]" id="view_monday" <?php echo in_array("2", $element) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>Monday
<input type="checkbox" value="3" data-day="3" name="opening_days[]" id="view_tuesday" <?php echo in_array("3", $element) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>Tuesday
<input type="checkbox" value="4" data-day="4" name="opening_days[]" id="view_wednesday" <?php echo in_array("4", $element) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>Wednesday
<input type="checkbox" value="5" data-day="5" name="opening_days[]" id="view_thursday" <?php echo in_array("5", $element) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>Thursday
<input type="checkbox" value="6" data-day="6" name="opening_days[]" id="view_friday" <?php echo in_array("6", $element) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>Friday
<input type="checkbox" value="7" data-day="7" name="opening_days[]" id="view_saturday" <?php echo in_array("7", $element) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>Saturday
```

### Edit 2

First of all, you should never write `HTML` on `model` or `controller` for that matter. Now to answer your question, look at the **Edit 1** part of my answer, that code will work. You only need to make sure not to use `PHP` tags as you're already writing `HTML` within `PHP` -

```
$output = '' ;
foreach($query->result() as $row){

    $output .= 'bla bla bla';
    $output .= '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$row->opening_days.'" id="special">'.$row->opening_days;

    $element = explode(",", $row->opening_days));

    $output .= '<input type="checkbox" value="1" data-day="1" name="opening_days[]" id="view_sunday" '. in_array("1", $element) ? "checked" : "".' >Sunday';
    $output .= '<input type="checkbox" value="2" data-day="2" name="opening_days[]" id="view_monday" '. in_array("2", $element) ? "checked" : "".' >Monday';
    $output .= '...'; // same for rest of the days
    $output .= 'bla bla bla';

    return $output;
}
```

You might run into some syntax error on the code above due to misplaced `{'}` or `{"}` or `{.}` but I'm sure you're able enough to fix them yourself.

Comment: how can i do this in my modal?

Comment: @AhmedMohammed I've updated my answer to answer your query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593651/passing-json-from-controller-to-view-in-codeigniter

Comment: how i will do it in front end as you are recommending? how can i view the single restaurant details when i click view and open modal?