# How to pass data controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting user profile fields from the database and want to display in my view but don't know to do this with the master layout.

this is my model

```
function fetchProfile($id,$page){
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM staff_master WHERE Id='$id'");
 return $query->result(); 
}
```

this is my controller:

```
public function edit($id,$page){
    $data['query'] =  $this->StaffModel->fetchProfile($id,$page);
    $data= array('content'=>'view_staff_edit');
    $this->load->view('template_master',$data);
}
```

I am also trying to find a solution. I am passing user Id and another by URL (get method).

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9446865/5530965

Comment: This is the official documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting `$data['query']` when you assign the array next:

```
$data['query'] =  $this->StaffModel->fetchProfile($id,$page);
$data= array('content'=>'view_staff_edit');
```

Either do:

```
$data= array('content'=>'view_staff_edit');
$data['query'] =  $this->StaffModel->fetchProfile($id,$page); // note position
```

Or:

```
$data = array(
    'content' = 'view_staff_edit',
    'query' => $this->StaffModel->fetchProfile($id,$page),
);
```

Access in view via `$query` and `$content`.

Unrelated:

You are also missing `$page` in your query, and its generally a good idea to declare gets as null if not set or you will get a notice: `public function edit($id=null,$page=null){`

Answer (score 2):

Your overriding your first declaration of variable `$data` what you can do is to initialize them both at the same time.

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id,$page){
    $data = array(
        'query'   => $this->StaffModel->fetchProfile($id,$page),
        'content' => 'view_staff_edit'
    );
    $this->load->view('template_master',$data);
}
```

Then access it on your **View** file

```
<h1><?php echo $content ?></h1>

<?php foreach($query as $result): ?>

    <p><?php echo $result->id ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
public function edit($id,$page) {

    $data['query'] =  $this->StaffModel->fetchProfile($id,$page);
    $data['content']= 'view_staff_edit';
    $this->load->view('template_master',$data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOUR MODEL

```
function fetchProfile($id){
    return $this->db->get_where('Id' => $id)->result_array(); 
}
```

YOUR CONTROLLER

```
public function edit($id,$page){
$data = array(
    'query'   => $this->StaffModel->fetchProfile($id),
    'content' => 'view_staff_edit',   
);
$this->load->view('template_master',$data);
}
```

YOUR "template_master" VIEW

```
<?php foreach ($query as $res){?>
<span><?php echo $res['Id'];?></span> //User html content according to your requirements ALSO you can add all columns retrieved from database
<?php } ?>
```