# Undefined variable 'data' after input some query to variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm sorry I have a question, I want to get data from query and send it to view..
Here's my code..

```
$this->load->model('expert_model');
$data = $this->expert_model->get_result($consultation_id);

$datas = $this->db->select('*')->limit(1)->order_by('CF_Combine', 'DESC')->get_where('hasil', ['id_konsultasi' => $consultation_id])->row();
        
$this->load->view('User/value', $datas);
```

I have tried dump the $datas and the result is all I want. But, How can I get data from $datas to the User/value's view ? I tried to use $datas but it said undefined 'datas'

I'm sorry I really bad both in english and code :(

And here's my code in view, just want to see it works or not

```
<?php foreach ($datas as $key) : ?>
<?php echo number_format(($key->CF_Combine * 100), 2) . " %" ?>                   
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Why not check the docs?  Top result when searching for "codeigniter view". It would be faster than writing a question! :-) https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codeigniter: Passing data from controller to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446700/codeigniter-passing-data-from-controller-to-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->load->model('expert_model');
$datas=array();  //define $datas is array
$data = $this->expert_model->get_result($consultation_id);

$datas['datas'] = $this->db->select('*')->limit(1)->order_by('CF_Combine', 'DESC')->get_where('hasil', ['id_konsultasi' => $consultation_id])->row();
        
$this->load->view('User/value', $datas);
```

Comment: it works, thank you! but I have another problem. It said 'Trying to get property 'CF_Combine' of non-object

Comment: $key->CF_Combine change to $key['CF_Combine']

Comment: foreach($datas as row){$row['CF_Combine'];} using loop

Comment: $datas as row as $key?

Comment: <?php echo $datas['CF_Combine']; ?> using only one data fetch

Comment: it only show string(1) "7" and error 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'

Comment: <?php foreach ($datas as $key) : ?>
<?php echo number_format(($key['CF_Combine'] * 100), 2) . " %" ?>                   
<?php endforeach ?>

Comment: Hey I have solved my problem! thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235653/discussion-between-ganpat-thakor-and-peb-mpeeb).

Answer (score 0):

Error `Undefined variable 'data'` says that you are trying to use variable `data` but you send in view `datas`, with `s` in the end. Try to change the variable name for the same either in view or in controller.

**UPDATE**
You should not use `datas` variable directly in the view. You need to call  variables that correspond to the array keys in your data.
For example:
if you have `$datas['name']` key - in view you should use just `$name`.
**In your case just use `$datas['datas'] =` instead of `$datas =`**

Comment: I have change the variable in view to datas but it said undefined too :(

Comment: please, take a look on UPDATE and let me know if it works for you

Comment: I have add my view in my question

Comment: @PebMpeeb see updates :) it should work out

Comment: it works, thank you! but I have another problem. It said 'Trying to get property 'CF_Combine' of non-object'

Comment: `$key->CF_Combine` change to `$key['CF_Combine']`.

Comment: it said 'Illegal string offset 'CF_Combine''. I want to use number format in the CF_Combine values ;(

Comment: make a <?php var_dump($key); ?>  in the loop

Comment: it show string(1) "7" , 700.00 % string(1) "3", 300.00 % string(1) "1", 100.00 % string(8) "0.920388", The right result is should be oonly 92.03% because I use the number_format :( it also show error like 'Message: Illegal string offset 'CF_Combine'

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert at CodeIgniter, but I can imagine where the error might be.

It seems that passing the row in the view doesn't work, because of what your view expects as data.

If inside your view code you have something as `$datas->id`, then your call should be `$this->load->view('User/value', ['datas'=>$datas]);`