# How to create a web service in zend-soap (or laminas-soap) with parameters with hyphens in their name?

Tags: php, zend-soap

I'm trying to create my first web service with zend-soap, but I need it to have some parameters with hyphens (like `parameter-name`). I have to implement a given WSDL so I can't change this requirement.

How can I do it, since PHP doesn't allow variables with hyphens?

Comment: I hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322315/how-to-declare-dynamic-php-class-with-property-names-like-this

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the autodiscover functionality? The class attributes are being converted to the WSDL parameters so you have to go by the attribute syntax of PHP. So in this situation I think it's only possible if you make your own WSDL or make a core change in Zend, but I don't think that would be a good advice.